# Connect reactjs component from another file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, reactjs

I develop test project from Rails and React.

I have root component from react:

```
# chat_app.js.jsx.coffee
###* @jsx React.DOM ###
@ChatApp = React.createClass

displayName: 'chatApp'

render: ->

    return (
        `<div className="chatApp">
            <h1>React Chat App Example</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div><MessageList /></div>
            </div>
        </div>`
        )

React.renderComponent(
  window.ChatApp(null),
  document.getElementById('chatApp')
)
```

and I have another component:

```
# message_list.js.jsx.coffee
###* @jsx React.DOM ###
@MessageList = React.createClass

    displayName: 'messageList'

    render: ->
        return (
            `<div className="messageList">
                qwe
            </div>`
            )
```

But in browser I have: Uncaught ReferenceError: MessageList is not defined

How I can connect MessageList to ChatApp?

Comment: You'll need to make sure that both MessageList and ChatApp are on the page before the call to React.renderComponent. Check the order of the script tags in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Rails, you can have all your JSX files in a `components` folder inside `app/assets/javascripts` and create another file, `app/assets/javascripts/components.js` with:

```
//= require_tree ./components
```

Make sure your `application.js` file has `//= require_tree .` (or add `//= require components`) and you will have:

- all your components loaded for you from within the default javascript include tag in your application layout
- the possibility to pre-render your components on the server before serving a page

I've just described the process in details in this blog post: [Isomorphic React app
with Ruby on Rails](https://medium.com/@olance/isomorphic-reactjs-app-with-ruby-on-rails-part-1-server-side-rendering-8438bbb1ea1c)