# reactjs communicating between multiple file

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs and trying to understand architecting a reactjs application. I have created two different js files with react code ( `spc.js` and `index.js`) The `spc.js` file contains all the reusable component definitions while the `index.js` consists of the calling component and the `reactDom` function. Both this files are called from an index.html file. please find the code below.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Investor Relations</title>
    <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="spc.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="spticker_content">
    </div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="sharepriceticker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="../default/sharepriceticker/sharepriceticker.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

spc.js

```
   var Companyname = React.createClass({
     render: function() {
       return ( < div className = "company_name" > {
         this.props.compname
       } < /div>            );
     }
   });

   var Exchange = React.createClass({
     render: function() {
       return ( < span className = "exch_text" > {
         this.props.exchange
       } < /span>);
     }
   });
```

index.js

```
var Sharepriceticker = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return(
        <div className="spticker">
            <div className="heading">
                <Companyname compname="Indus Gas"/>
                <Exchange exchange="(LON:INDI)"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );   
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Sharepriceticker/>,
    document.getElementById('spticker_content')
);
```

My code works fine if i combine the spc.js and index.js in single file, however it doesnt work if i seperate the two files

Thanks

Comment: You need to include `spj.js` into index.js to use it.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499083/connect-reactjs-component-from-another-file

Comment: any help on how to include spc.js in index.js would be great looking for the same.

Comment: for combine two file you have to use webpack or browserify which can minified your two js and create one bundle file https://webpack.github.io/ also you have to use commonJs pattern which can give you accessibility of import and export the file

Comment: Can you add the console log displayed when the page fails to render as expected?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to set your classes on the global scope.  For example, your spc.js could be:

```js
(function (app) {
  app.reactClasses = app.reactClasses || { };

  app.reactClasses.Companyname = React.createClass({
     render: function() {
       return ( < div className = "company_name" > {
         this.props.compname
       } < /div>            );
     }
   });

  app.reactClasses.Exchange = React.createClass({
     render: function() {
       return ( < span className = "exch_text" > {
         this.props.exchange
       } < /span>);
     }
   });
})(window.app || (window.app = { }))
```

Then your index.js could have:

```js
<app.reactClasses.Companyname compname="Indus Gas"/>
<app.reactClasses.Exchange exchange="(LON:INDI)"/>
```

I hope this helps! (:

Comment: finaly a solution which does not recommend an approach which includes systemjs or something else,

Answer (score 1):

The combination should not be the part of react you have to use the common js pattern with `require` 
let's say I have two component A and B
my A component should be like

```
var A=React.createClass({
  render:function()
   {
    return(
       // html content goes here
      )
    }
});
```

my Component B look like

```
 var B=React.createClass({
      render:function()
       {
        return(
           // html content goes here
          )
        }
    }); 
   module.exports = B;
```

now if I want to use component A in Component B then I must have to use `export.modules=A` in component A and in Component B I have to import the component A like

in ES5

```
var A=require('B');
```

in ES6

```
import A from 'B'
```

now you can use the component A in your B Component like

```
var A=React.createClass({
  render:function()
   {
    return(
       <A />
      )
    }
});
```

Comment: @CharanCherry : you need use module.exports = B in Component B see my updated ans\